# Query firestore document to drive a widget selection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget, future

I'm trying to check a user document in firebase so I can then determine which widget to show them. Basically, show them a welcome message first time they access the app.

So I've been stumbling around with something like this. I know this isn't right but it the flow that I'm try to achieve.

I suspect that I need to refactor to use a future (which I've tried with no success) but I can't figure out how to the get result of a future into a variable so that I can drive the logic.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### db.dart

```
userDetails(FirebaseUser user) async {

 final document = await _db.collection('users').document(user.uid).get(); 
 final userObject = document.data;
 return (userObject);

}
```

#### profile.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 

 final db = DatabaseService();
 var user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

 var userdata = db.userDetails(user);
 var showWidget;

 if (!userdata.welcome){
   showWidget = _profileScreen();
 }else{
   showWidget = _welcomeScreen();
 }

 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppTopNav('User Profile').build(context),
   body: showWidget,
   bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNav(),    
 );
}
```

Comment: So you want to have the standard "onboarding" screens when the users enters your app? But then you cant ask the DB because at this point in time, you dont know the user yet. I ve chosen a different path. I write to the system.preferences the first time the user enters the app on the device and if nothing is written yet, i present the onboarding screens. If thats what you want, i can show you how....

Comment: Thanks Marc. When the user registers I've a cloud function that creates a user profile document, which has a field called 'welcomed' defaulted to false. So after they authenticate and land on the 'account' screen I'd like to be able to query the db and direct them one way or the other. After they go through the welcome screens their profile is updated accordingly.

I'll have other areas of the application where I'll need to do db looks like this so I'd prefer to use the query / future approach - but thanks all the same. I'll keep the system preferences in mind for other areas.